# R multiply unequal dataframes based on specific column values

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, mapply

*Updated question to include extra columns that pass from df1 to output, as well as add that the main df has 7 million rows.*

---

I have two dataframes, similar to [Pandas SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227284/how-to-multiply-2-unequal-dataframes-based-on-column-values)

And I need to multiply them where the names match. I'm not sure how to accomplish this cleanly. is there an apply function that does this easily?

**DF1:**  (there are 16 columns of extra data, 7 million rows long)

```
Data1   Data2   Name      Value
aa      bb      sample1   50
ff      ff      sample1   100
ef      fd      sample1   75
ff      df      sample2   100
bbf     ad3     sample2   200
dd      a       sample2   300
33      3rf     sample3   25
ddd     dd      sample3   50
dd      dd      sample3   40
```

**DF2:**

```
Name      Value
sample1   1
sample2   0.5
sample3   2
```

**OUTPUT:** (With the additional 16 columns that aren't shown)

```
Data1   Data2   Name      Value
aa      bb      sample1   50
ff      ff      sample1   100
ef      fd      sample1   75
ff      df      sample2   50
bbf     ad3     sample2   100
dd      a       sample2   150
33      3rf     sample3   50
ddd     dd      sample3   100
dd      dd      sample3   80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can join both the dataframes using a `left_join` or an `inner_join` and then multiply the corresponding `Value` columns with one another. Using `dplyr` that can be done as :

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'Name') %>%
   mutate(Value = Value.x * Value.y) %>%
   select(names(df1))

#     Name Value
#1 sample1    50
#2 sample1   100
#3 sample1    75
#4 sample2    50
#5 sample2   100
#6 sample2   150
#7 sample3    50
#8 sample3   100
#9 sample3    80
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"), class = "factor"), 
Value = c(50L, 100L, 75L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 25L, 50L, 40L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df2 <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("sample1", "sample2", 
"sample3"), class = "factor"), Value = c(1, 0.5, 2)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I've updated the question to include the size of the dataframes and the extra columns that need to pass through.  I'm going to try implementing each of these answers, but i thought the information may be relevant.

Comment: @Steve I don't think anything changes in my answer with additional columns.

Answer (score 2):

Most straightforward would be to use `match` to get the row indices of `df2` in proper order.

```
df2$Value[match(df1$Name, df2$Name)] * df1$Value
```

You could also convert `df2` to vector with names based on `Name` column. Then subset values from it using the `Name` column of `df1`.

```
df1$Value * setNames(df2$Value, df2$Name)[df1$Name]
```

Comment: I've updated the question to include the size of the dataframes and the extra columns that need to pass through.  I'm going to try implementing each of these answers, but i thought the information may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the base R code below, using `merge`

```
DF1$Value <- do.call(`*`,merge(DF1[c("Name","Value")],DF2,all = TRUE,by="Name")[-1])
```

such that

```
> DF1
  Data1 Data2    Name Value
1    aa    bb sample1    50
2    ff    ff sample1   100
3    ef    fd sample1    75
4    ff    df sample2    50
5   bbf   ad3 sample2   100
6    dd     a sample2   150
7    33   3rf sample3    50
8   ddd    dd sample3   100
9    dd    dd sample3    80
```

**DATA**

```
DF1 <- structure(list(Data1 = c("aa", "ff", "ef", "ff", "bbf", "dd", 
"33", "ddd", "dd"), Data2 = c("bb", "ff", "fd", "df", "ad3", 
"a", "3rf", "dd", "dd"), Name = c("sample1", "sample1", "sample1", 
"sample2", "sample2", "sample2", "sample3", "sample3", "sample3"
), Value = c(50L, 100L, 75L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 25L, 50L, 40L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

DF2 <- structure(list(Name = c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"), Value = c(1, 
0.5, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I've updated the question to include the size of the dataframes and the extra columns that need to pass through.  I'm going to try implementing each of these answers, but i thought the information may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), Value_new := Value * i.Value, on = "Name"]

#     Data1  Data2    Name Value Value_new
# 1:     aa     bb sample1    50        50
# 2:     ff     ff sample1   100       100
# 3:     ef     fd sample1    75        75
# 4:     ff     df sample2   100        50
# 5:    bbf    ad3 sample2   200       100
# 6:     dd      a sample2   300       150
# 7:     33    3rf sample3    25        50
# 8:    ddd     dd sample3    50       100
# 9:     dd     dd sample3    40        80
```

Comment: I've updated the question to include the size of the dataframes and the extra columns that need to pass through.  I'm going to try implementing each of these answers, but i thought the information may be relevant.